# discrete universal distribution probability

Tags: probability, distribution

if `x` is an integer randomly generated from a discrete universal distribution of (-2^53, 2^53], that is, we randomly (not in a mathematical way) choose an integer between (-2^53, 2^53], what is the probability P ( x + 1 === x) ?

Tips from Probability 101: A discrete universal distribution X of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] is P(X = i) = ⅙, i = 1, 2, …, 6.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "uniform", not "universal".  And your question makes no sense -- `x+1 != x` unless `x` is ±infinity, and you've finitely bounded the range.

Comment: What is this `discrete universal distribution`? Could you provide its properties?

Comment: @pjs i think i know what was asked, take a look at the answer

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Your interpretation makes sense.  If you're right I'd advise OP to change notation to `X(i+1) == X(i)`, where `X(i)` is the i-th observation.  (Subscripts would be better, but don't seem to work in comments.)  As written, it's nonsense.

Comment: @pjs yes, I agree. zhangxudong could you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood the question, you're asking what's the probability that freshly sampled number is equal to the previous one. Well, that probability is equal to 2<sup>-54</sup> for discrete universal (uniform) distribution.